# Every subset of R can be contained in a measurable set?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Is the following true? If so why?

Let $G$ be a $G_{\delta}$ set. Then for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists a measurable bounded set $G_n$ such that

1. $G_n \subseteq G.$
2. $m^*(G) \leq m^*(G_n) + \frac{1}{n}.$

I know that given any $A \in \mathscr{P}(\mathbb{R})$ and $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists \mathcal{O}$ open, such that, $A \subseteq \mathcal{O}$ and $m^*(\mathcal{O}) \leq m^*(A) + \epsilon$. However, $G$ need not be open...hence I do not think this property can be used to deduce the above result.

Also, are $G_{\delta}$ sets, in general, measurable?

Comment: $G_\delta$ sets are always measurable.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thank you, why is that the case however?

Comment: Do you already know that the measurable sets are closed under countable intersections?

Comment: @NoahSchweber I do not. Does this follow that a countable union of measurable sets is measurable and that the set of measurable sets form a sigma algebra, therefore, by de morgan the results holds?

Comment: Yes, the measurable sets form a $\sigma$-algebra containing the open sets. In particular, every Borel set is measurable - and indeed one characterization of measurability is that $X$ is measurable iff there is some Borel set $Y$ such that $X\Delta Y$ is null (here "$\Delta$" is the symmetric difference operation).

Answer (score 1):

Never mind! I see that problem 7 in Royden says that given any bounded set $E$, there is a $G_{\delta}$ set $G$ for which

1. $E \subseteq G$
2. $m^*(G) = m^*(E)$

If you take $E = G_n$ bounded, for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then you get

1. $G_n \subseteq G$
2. $m^*(G) = m^*(G_n) \implies m^*(G) \leq m^*(G_n) + \frac{1}{n},$

as desired.